# Task list manager (aka Todo list) for Android with non-Google syncing?

Tags: gratis, android, productivity, synchronization

TickTick has further limited the functionality available to free users.  (Without sending any emails to notify them of the changes.)  At the same time, they increased the cost to paid users.

Consequently, I am looking for a new task manager for myself and to recommend to others.

Are there any *gratis* task list managers that have the following features:

Required features:

1. Android app
2. Create tasks and assign them a due date
3. Support recurring tasks
4. Organize tasks by folders and/or tags
5. Sync tasks across two devices

Optional features:

1. Assign priority to tasks
2. Web app
3. Windows app
4. Linux app

Features not needed:

1. Calendar integration

Must **not** require:

1. Google tasks/calendar

***Big bonus feature (optional, but would be great!):***

1. Support import from TickTick

Comment: Plenty. Some [Sync mit Toodledo](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_24), some use [other sync services](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_25) (including your own, e.g. via ownCloud). Not sure about your "bonus feature", though :)